# Stored procedure: take rows with summary resilts and place them in output parameters

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

Lets take a simple query

```
SELECT SUM(Field1), Field2 FROM TableName GROUP BY Field2
```

In my case I know for a fact that there are MAX 5 distinct values for field2 (1-5), so this query will return maximum 5 rows (could be less, if for example, there are no records with Field2 value = 2).

What I am interesting in is storing a value from `SUM(field1)` into the `OUTPUT` parameter, based on the `Field2` value it belongs to. Currently I do this from stored procedure (simplified):

```
SELECT @prm1 = SUM(Field1) FROM TableName WHERE Field2=1
SELECT @prm2 = SUM(Field1) FROM TableName WHERE Field2=2
SELECT @prm3 = SUM(Field1) FROM TableName WHERE Field2=3
SELECT @prm4 = SUM(Field1) FROM TableName WHERE Field2=4
SELECT @prm5 = SUM(Field1) FROM TableName WHERE Field2=5
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Edit: this stored procedure is executing more than 10 queries and fetching summary from each of them. I have made a decision not to execute 10+ different queries separately from client, but place them in one stored procedure and then return results through output parameters. Those queries will not have a purpose of calling them alone, only as a batch. However, if you think that this is not a good idea, I will listen to your arguments.

Comment: Why does it have to be an output parameter? Why not just return the resultset of the `SELECT`? You will need to include in your question how you are using these outputs.

Comment: Because I am calculating approx 12-15 summary values and returning them to my application. So instead of executing 12 different queries from my application, I execute them through one stored procedure, and pass results to application through output parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with conditional `SUM()`

```sql
SELECT @prm1 = SUM(CASE WHEN field2 = 1 THEN field1 ELSE NULL END), 
       @prm2 = SUM(CASE WHEN field2 = 2 THEN field1 ELSE NULL END), 
       @prm3 = SUM(CASE WHEN field2 = 3 THEN field1 ELSE NULL END), 
       @prm4 = SUM(CASE WHEN field2 = 4 THEN field1 ELSE NULL END), 
       @prm5 = SUM(CASE WHEN field2 = 5 THEN field1 ELSE NULL END) 
  FROM Table1
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/acdc4/4)** demo